# Highlight words that do not match the given string

Tags: javascript, regex

What I'd like to do: when the user finishes typing in some text, I want this text to be tested against another string. If they don't match, I want the symbols that failed the test to be highlighted / colored red. So far I was only able to come up with the following code

```js
let string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

let input = document.querySelector(".js-textarea");

let receivedValue = "";

let checkValue = function() {
  let regex = new RegExp(string,"g");
 
  receivedValue = input.value;
  if(!regex.test(receivedValue)) {
    input.classList.add("error");
  };
}

input.addEventListener("change",checkValue);
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea-block">
  <textarea class="js-textarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

Just to see whether it is actually being tested, I color the border; but how can I get the symbols/words that don't pass the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used a style red for the entire div, and then wrap matched text with a span with style black.  Also added ^$ to force match whole string for the test, so the whole string has to match for it to ignore it.
You could also use '(.*?)('+string+')(.*?)' and wrap the 1st and 3rd capture groups with error spans.

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but roughly guessing what you are trying to do:

```js
let string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

let input = document.querySelector(".js-textarea");

let receivedValue = "";

let checkValue = function() {
  let regex1 = new RegExp(string,"g");
  let regex = new RegExp('^'+string+'$',"g");
 
  receivedValue = input.value;
  if(!regex.test(receivedValue)) {
      document.getElementById('errorbox').innerHTML=receivedValue.replace(regex1,'<span class="matches">$&</span>');
//    input.classList.add("error");
  }
}

input.addEventListener("change",checkValue);
checkValue()
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.matches {
   color: black
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea-block">
  <textarea class="js-textarea">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. Jack</textarea>
</div>

<span id="errorbox" style="color:red"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `textarea` element does not provide a way to apply styling to individual words so the easiest way would be to add an error message below the input element. [This answer shows how that can be accomplished.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62099398/13470754)

There is the hard way, though.

You can use an HTML element with the `contenteditable` attribute. This lets users edit the contents of the HTML element. If you give it a border and a use a white background it will look just like a `textarea` element.

In this example I chose to highlight with green the text that matches the string and everything else with red.

```js
let string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

let input = document.querySelector("div");

input.addEventListener("focus", () => {
  // Remove styling so as to not distract the user.
  for (let i = 0; i < input.children.length; i++) {
      input.children[i].className = "";
  }
});

input.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  // We will recreate styling tags. This is under the assumption that the
  // element will not have a lot of text.
  let value = input.textContent;
  input.textContent= "";

  let failPoint = -1;

  for (var i = 0; i < string.length && i < value.length; i++) {
      if (value[i].toLowerCase() !== string[i].toLowerCase()) {
          failPoint = i;
          break;
      }
  }

  let good = document.createElement("span");
  good.classList.add("success");
  good.textContent = value.substring(0, failPoint !== -1 ? failPoint : value.length);
  input.append(good);

  if (failPoint !== -1) {
      let bad = document.createElement("span");
      bad.classList.add("error");
      bad.textContent = value.substring(i);
      input.append(bad);
  }
});
```

```css
.editable {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: white;
    color: #020202;
    padding: 2px;
    word-break: break-all;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.success {
  color: green;
}

.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="editable" contenteditable spellcheck="false"></div>
```